# Java 2D API: Null Pointer Exception

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, nullpointerexception, java-2d

Please have a look at the following code

```
package java2D;

import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Joins extends JFrame
{
    private JPanel centerPanel;

    public Joins()
    {   
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.add(createCenterPanel(),"Center");

        this.setSize(200,250);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    private JPanel createCenterPanel()
    {
        centerPanel = new JPanel();
        //centerPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        Graphics g = centerPanel.getGraphics();

        Graphics2D g2d =  (Graphics2D)g;

        BasicStroke bs1 = new BasicStroke(8, BasicStroke.CAP_ROUND, BasicStroke.JOIN_BEVEL);
        g2d.setStroke(bs1);
        g2d.drawRect(15, 15, 80, 50);

        BasicStroke bs2 = new BasicStroke(8, BasicStroke.CAP_ROUND, BasicStroke.JOIN_MITER);
        g2d.setStroke(bs2);
        g2d.drawRect(125, 15, 80, 50);

        BasicStroke bs3 = new BasicStroke(8, BasicStroke.CAP_ROUND, BasicStroke.JOIN_ROUND);
        g2d.setStroke(bs3);
        g2d.drawRect(235, 15, 80, 50);


        return centerPanel;
    }

    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Joins();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This code generates NullPointerException. I need to draw the graphics inside the `centerPanel`. When I develop Swing applications, I normally divide the JFrame area into number of JPanels, and I did it here too, but ended up with NullPointerException!

Following is the error

```
run:
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java2D.Joins.createCenterPanel(Joins.java:34)
    at java2D.Joins.<init>(Joins.java:17)
    at java2D.Joins$1.run(Joins.java:55)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:705)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:666)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:664)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:675)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 6 seconds)
```

Please help!

Comment: Add your stacktrace to the question please.

Comment: @Perception: Sorry, I added it

Comment: Yikes! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8356111/drawing-on-a-jpanel You should really consider extending JPanel and drawing via paintComponent (Specifically for this reason). You're looking for a lot of buggy behavior if you draw directly to it (repaint etc...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As has already been pointed out, `Graphics g = centerPanel.getGraphics();` is the source of your problem.

You should never use getGraphics to perform custom painting.  At best `getGraphics` is a snapshot of the last paint cycle, at worst, well, you've seen the worst result, it's `null`

To perform custom painting you should create yourself a custom component (from something like a `JPanel` for example) and override its `paintComponent` method (don't forget to call `super.paintComponet`)

Take a look at [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details

Comment: Thank you for the reply. In that case, I MUST extends the JPanel right? hmm, not like swing :(

Comment: Yes, custom painting must be done within the repaint managers paint cycles. Take a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html). Swing has a reasonably high learning curve, but once you get to understand it, it is among one if the most powerful UI toolkits around - IMHO

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `getGraphics`. Create a new `JPanel` and place your paint functionality into the `paintComponent` method remembering to call `super.paintComponent(g)`.

Answer (score 1):

The mistake is at:

```
Graphics g = centerPanel.getGraphics();
```

According to javadocs:

> Creates a graphics context for this component. This method will return `null` if this component is currently not displayable.

Maybe you need to first add the `JPanel` to your `Joins` frame, so after you can use `getGraphics()`?

Comment: Your assessment is right, your advice is not. My should never use getGraphics to perform custom painting

Answer (score -1):

Nothing is visible, thus getGraphics() returns null. Try:

```
    centerPanel = new JPanel();
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.add(centerPanel);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    centerPanel.setVisible(true);
```